# Defining localstorage for angular2 app

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using localStorage in an authentication service in one app. Now I am migrating the old app to a new project structure with webpack. Of course, I have different `package.json` files, but I do not know which specific node module I need.

This is the error:

```
Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined
```

The component for login is entirely copied to the new project, and it has not any compilation errors, I added the component and authentication service to my `app.module` but I get that error.

How do I set up `package.json` and `app.module.ts` files for defining `localStorage`?

These are the files:

`app.module.ts`

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { UniversalModule } from 'angular2-universal';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
// import { DataTableModule, SharedModule} from 'primeng/primeng';

import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component'
import { NavMenuComponent } from './components/navmenu/navmenu.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { FetchDataComponent } from './components/fetchdata/fetchdata.component';
import { CounterComponent } from './components/counter/counter.component';

import { AuthenticationService } from './components/login/authentication.service';

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        NavMenuComponent,
        CounterComponent,
        FetchDataComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        LoginComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        AuthenticationService
    ],
    imports: [
        UniversalModule, // Must be first import. This automatically imports BrowserModule, HttpModule, and JsonpModule too.
        FormsModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
            { path: 'counter', component: CounterComponent },
            { path: 'fetch-data', component: FetchDataComponent },
            { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' },
        ])
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "Angular2Spa",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.38",
    "angular2-platform-node": "~2.0.10",
    "angular2-universal": "~2.0.10",
    "angular2-universal-polyfills": "~2.0.10",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^1.0.6",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^1.0.11",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "css": "^2.2.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.1",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "jquery": "^2.2.1",
    "preboot": "^4.5.2",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "ts-loader": "^0.8.2",
    "typescript": "^2.0.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^1.12.14",
    "webpack-externals-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.10.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^0.14.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.21"
  }
}
```

This is the code where the error is produced:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {
    public token: string;
    public codusuario: string;
    constructor(private http: Http) {
        // set token if saved in local storage
        var currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
        this.token = currentUser && currentUser.token;
    }

login(username, password): Observable<boolean> {
    //...
}

logout(): void {
    // clear token remove user from local storage to log user out
    this.token = null;
    localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
}
```

}

Comment: which code throwing the error ? share the code here which is throwing error.

Comment: OK, I updated my anwer. Also I tried adding `window.localStorage.getItem` but it says: window is not defined

Comment: which module is suppose to contain the local storage functionality? Have you considered angular2-localstorage?

Comment: But in my other project (from yeoman aspcore angular2 generator) I did not added it to my `package.json` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

localStorage should be defined at global JS level, but you don't have the Typescript definition for it so the compiler says that is not defined.

Just try to put at the start of the file

> declare var localStorage : any;

and then use localStorage in the TypeScript code.

You can also try to use angular2-localstorage module.

Comment: What file are you saying we should put it at the start of?