# TypeScript Cannot find module occurs too often

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core

It took about 10 hours since I am trying some simple jobs using typescript, angular2 and asp core. I will explain the path I reached here and where you have any idea i will appreciate.

First you should consider that I am using a project template from the link bellow:

[Template](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/10/04/angular2-template-for-visual-studio/)

Then I wanted to add some code to store some data in localStorage.

Some links suggest that I must have access to localStorage very simple. But when I wanted to access localStorage from within the component of angular2, I got this error:

`localStorage is not defined`

Then I googled a lot for a solution and found libraries below:

[angular2-localstorage](https://github.com/marcj/angular2-localstorage)

[angular-2-local-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-2-local-storage)

[angular2-local-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-local-storage)

But all of them won't work.

Then I tried writing a service will the hope of accessing localStorage easily. Then I created this file:

/ClientApp/app/services/local-storage-service.ts

```
export class LocalStorageService {
    write(key: string, value: any) {
        if (value) {
            value = JSON.stringify(value);
        }
        localStorage.setItem(key, value);
    }

    read<T>(key: string): T {
        let value: string = localStorage.getItem(key);

        if (value && value != "undefined" && value != "null") {
            return <T>JSON.parse(value);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

but when I try to import that like this:

```
import { LocalStorageService } from 'services/local-storage-service';
```

I got this error:

```
cannot find module 'services/local-storage-service'
```

I have tried everything you can guess. The weird part is that the import bellow works fine:

```
import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component';
```

that the file is at '/ClientApp/app/app.component.ts' but when I copy that file to '/services/app.component.ts' the same error occures.

I don't have enough idea about how to ask question about this problem. But I will try any Idea of yours.

****UPDATE
This is the directory tree:

[image: Directory Tree]

Although in the file app.modules.ts I can access it like this:

```
import { LocalStorageService } from './services/local-storage.service';
```

without error. but at the file settoken.component.ts it causes error.

***REUPDATE

Now with the correct path I have the service Injected. But it says localStorage is not defined!
The service code is the one suggested.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class LocalStorageService {
    private storage: any;

    constructor() {
        this.storage = localStorage;
    }

    public retrieve(key: string): any {
        var item = this.storage.getItem(key);

        if (item !== null && item !== 'undefined') {
            return JSON.parse(this.storage.getItem(key));
        }

        return;
    }

    public store(key: string, value: any) {
        this.storage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
    }

}
```

and the error:

```
Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined
ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined
```

TG.

Comment: Isn't a `./` or `../` missing from the import path? Generally only node modules can start without those in imports, unless you are doing some magic with your bundler (which I'm not sure if ts is aware of)

Comment: according to "https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#relative-vs-non-relative-module-imports" the non-relative paths will be tried on any parent directory. But I tried the ones you mentioned. Nothing changed!

Comment: Hmm, I didn't know about this, learned something new today! Thanks! Sorry it wasn't useful for you.

Comment: Your welcome. Additional question: can be this because of webpack or something else?

Comment: Absolutely not sure. Webpack with it's loaders makes it kinda difficult do figure out where the error comes from.

Comment: What module strategy did you configure TS to use? And why don't you just use relative paths? Non relative paths are for third party modules typically. Compile using --traceResolution and you'll find out what it's looking for

Comment: @JuanMendes I have tried relative path. The location that it says nothing is found is the currect location!!!

Comment: For settoken.component.ts you want to use  `'../services/local-storage.service'`

Comment: Oh. it is solved! by this path "import { LocalStorageService } from '../../services/local-storage.service';" let me find the reason. Because I've tried all these ways before.

Comment: Right. That's actually what I meant. :P It most likely had to do with a bad symbol or something that slipped by you. Happens to me every day.

Comment: Thanks @J.AdamConnor. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For non-module files you're going to have to use relative paths; e.g., `./`, `../`. You don't say where the file is that is trying to import the service in relation to the service. Assuming it's in a parent directory, the path would be `./services/local-storage-service`.

If you're still having problems, you can try using this local storage service.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class LocalStoragePersistence {
    private storage:any;

    constructor() {
        this.storage = localStorage;
    }

    public retrieve(key:string):any {
        var item = this.storage.getItem(key);

        if (item !== null && item !== 'undefined') {
            return JSON.parse(this.storage.getItem(key));
        }

        return;
    }

    public store(key:string, value:any) {
        this.storage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
    }

}
```

Import it into your component with

```
import { LocalStoragePersistence } from './services/local-storage.service';
```

Make sure you remember to declare it in your providers array: `providers: [ LocalStoragePersistence ]`

Note the suggestion there to rename the file to `local-storage.service.ts`. This is the Angular 2 naming pattern for files (feature.type.ts). Hope this helps.

Comment: Your comments was good but not the answer yet. Please consider the UPDATE I've added. Any other idea?

Comment: Oh. it is solved! by this path "import { LocalStorageService } from '../../services/local-storage.service';" let me find the reason. Because I've tried all these ways before.

Comment: I think the problem is with one of the tools. now even without correct namings and without Injectables It works fine! But I'm sure I've tried all these before. I am suspicious about VS's functionality when in run mode.

Comment: please check the ***REUPDATE.

Comment: In the Index.html I've changed `<app asp-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/main-server">Loading...</app>` to `<app>Loading...</app>` and every thing goes right now! Do you know the reason?

Comment: I don't. I'm sorry. I have never used VS. But try the answer found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40026580/6024090) to see if you can keep the prerender-module statement. **Edit: Retry this link. I gave the wrong link initially.**